# How to skip current fieldset and continue the next in the spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have my own fieldsetmapper in the spring batch. I want to skip some line which meets some criterias. If I return the null in the mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet), the itemreader will stop. That means the remaining lines will not get processed.

So how to skip the line in the mapFieldSet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an exception and configure your batch reader's `skippable-exception-classes`. Remember to configure `skip-limit` too:

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="flatFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter"
             commit-interval="10" skip-limit="10">
         <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
         </skippable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```

Details here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html

Answer (score 5):

Parsing done by `FieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet()` returns a valid object if text line content is formally correct; the object returned should be "filtered out" (matching your business criteria) in `ItemProcessor` as described in ['Filtering records'](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#filiteringRecords) chapter.